# Datastax Enterprise 5.0 Installation Error after DSE removal

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

The following error occurs during the startup of a node when Lifecycle Manager is used to provision a cluster:

`ERROR 04:46:00,789  DseModule.java:98 - org/apache/hadoop/security/token/delegation/AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager. Exiting...`

This started to happen after I used a script meant for an older version of OptCenter to remove DSE:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.1/opsc/online_help/opscRemovingPackages_t.html

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up terminating the AWS EC2 instances and starting from scratch.